# VT-x isn't available & No Hyper-V manager on Windows 10

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, hyper-v

When I used `vagrant up` to boot a VM, I found the following **error ox80004005** (Note that I am using Oracle VM Virtualbox for the virtualization)

```
kayan@kayan-VirtualBox:~/vagrant/rpm$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'jhcook/fedora27' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["startvm", "769fc6c1-ea8d-46d8-8a7b-16989540d530", "--type", "gui"]

Stderr: VBoxManage: error: VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole
```

[Screenshot: VT-x isn't available ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKLuw.png)

I am using **64-bit** Windows 10. My processor is **Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7500U CPU @ 2.70 GHz**.

To solve this error, I was suggested by someone that I should disable **Hyper -v** on my host windows machine. When I opted to disable Hyper -v feature, I found that there is no Hyper-v in my machine (**strange**!!!)

[Screenshot: No option to enable or disable Hyper-v](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjSOY.png)

I then used this command `dism.exe /Online /Enable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V /All` to disable the hypervisor and I found this (Note: I run CMD as administrator).

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.125]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>dism.exe /Online /Enable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V /All

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.16299.15

Image Version: 10.0.16299.125


Error: 0x800f080c

Feature name Microsoft-Hyper-V is unknown.
A Windows feature name was not recognized.
Use the /Get-Features option to find the name of the feature in the image and try the command again.

The DISM log file can be found at C:\WINDOWS\Logs\DISM\dism.log

C:\WINDOWS\system32
```

[Screenshot: 0x800f080c ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBLZL.png)

My virtual machine configuration:

- OS: Ubuntu 16.04.03
- RAM: 3072 MB
- Storage: 500 GB
- storage type: VDI

Comment: Sounds like a VirtualBox bug, and you should contact Oracle support resources, or simply use other virtualization solutions. It is not programming related at all.

Comment: Thank you. I contacted them and solved the issue.

Comment: @Morshed, What was the solution?

Comment: @theblackpearl Oracle VM Virtualbox doesn't support nested 64-bit virtual machines.

My host machine is actually a 64-bit machine. I installed Oracle VM Virtualbox and installed a 64-bit Linux VM there. My target was to install another 64-bit Linux VM on that VM. Unluckily, Oracle VM Virtualbox doesn't provide us that support.

To solve this issue, I used VMWare to install the first VM. Then I installed Oracle VM Virtualbox on that VM and installed the second VM on VirtualBox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**(UPDATED)**
Oracle VM Virtualbox **doesn't support** nested 64-bit virtual machines.

My host machine is actually a 64-bit machine. I installed Oracle VM Virtualbox and installed a 64-bit Linux VM there. My target was to install another 64-bit Linux VM on that VM. Unluckily, Oracle VM Virtualbox doesn't provide us that support.

To solve this issue, I used VMWare to install the first VM. Then I installed Oracle VM Virtualbox on that VM and installed the second VM on VirtualBox.

Answer (score 4):

If you are facing the problem in VirtualBox after the Windows 10 Founder's Update, you need to turn Core Isolation Memory Integrity back off again. The UI  is bugged, here's how it can be done via. registry, navigate to below and set 0:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\DeviceGuard\Scenarios\HypervisorEnforcedCodeIntegrity\Enabled
```

Comment: This solves the problem if you have virtualization enabled on bios, and don't have hyper-v active.
It can be edited in gui by:
"Settings" -> "Update & Security" -> "Windows Security" -> "Device Security" -> "Core Isolation" -> Turn it off

Comment: Creating manually the registry key apparently did the job. Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me! Thanks! Just need to restart the PC to apply changes

Answer (score 2):

Hyper-V is not installed/available on windows 10 Home edition, which might be why you aren't seeing it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v

You need to change your Bios settings to enable Virtualization. 
https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/access-bios-windows-10

Once enabled, you'll be good to go with VirtualBox.

Comment: Here lies the actual problem. Virtualization is enabled in BiOS setting. Everything is okay with the BIOS setting I think. Still I am facing the above mentioned problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem when i want to run emulator and thanks to [bluedi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7150521/bluedi) solved this problem.

just disable **Memory Integrity**

"Settings" -> "Update & Security" -> "Windows Security" -> "Device Security" -> "Core Isolation" -> Turn it off

Answer (score 1):

I tried these two solutions without luck:

1. Enabling virtualization in BIOS
2. Disabling (or enable, then disable) Hyper-V

What finally worked was running this privileged command:

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

Run that command with `cmd` in Administrator mode and reboot.